# Cannot mount usb to linux terminal on Chromebook

Tags: linux-kernel, usb-drive, chrome-book

First and foremost, I deeply apologise for the way I outlined my question first time around. This is my first time asking a question on any of these servers, and I was in despair as I only wanted to use this as a last resort. I do believe one of the rules is to explain the question well, but I did not do that and once again, I apologise.

My issue is that I can not mount my **Sandisk UltraFit** to my **Linux terminal** on my **Acer Chromebook R11 (Cyan)**. I have tried various commands, like `lsusb`, `lsblk`, and `fdisk -l`, but my **flash drive** is not showing up because it is not **mounted**. But, no matter what **package** I download from the **terminal**, for instance *autofs* or *pmount*, that are to help with automounting on Linux, I always seem to be missing something from these packages, thus hitting a dead end, with **errors**.

**Error #1** Now, when I *share my file with Linux* on my Chromebook, the **usb** will show in the file `/mnt/chromeos/removable/USB`. I looked up why that happened, and it is because the file is shared, but the device is not mounted.

**Error #2** Linux will tell me the device is not in `/etc/fstab`, something along that line, so I use the **command** `cat /etc/fstab` and I get a **comment** `#UNCONFIGURED FSTAB FOR BASE SYSTEM`. I am not sure if I am to **edit the file**, but the same comment shows when I do open the file to edit.

I have run into plenty of other errors, but I feel these are the ones that have gotten me anywhere. One thing I would like to know is if **Linux on Chromebook** is any different from Linux anywhere else. If there are any suggestions or questions I am very willing to hear. I wish to **download Ubuntu** to my **drive** through terminal, but can not because my **device is not mounted**. I am sorry for the long read, but I hope this outlines my issue way more.

Comment: It's absolutely not clear what you're doing and trying to achieve. Also a wall of text rarely helps. Please use paragraphs.

Comment: There is more than one way to install "Linux" on your Chromebook. The [least destructive way](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/9145439?hl=en) does not require mounting USB storage. Please rephrase your question. Tell us exactly what you do to try to accomplish your goal step by step and provide all the output and error messages from the commands you enter. If it is reproducible we may be able to help you, but at the moment nobody reading your question knows what you do and we will therefore close it.

Comment: If you access your usb via `/mnt/chromeos/removable/USB`, it means it is already mounted on that directory. You cannot mount it do `/dev`. `/dev`is a system directory for access to devices, and that has been transferred to the directory you describe. Do not mess with `/dev`, because you will ruin something. Your question is confusing and it is not clear what exactly are you doing.

Comment: What means that you share the file? For mounting a drive temporarily you do not need to edit /etc/fstab. You have to write a mount command where the first parameter is the partition from your sandisk and the second parameter is the directory where you want your drive to be accessible.

Answer (score 1):

In general: If you ask a question then tell us the facts and expectations and leave the interpretations to us.

If `lsusb`, `lsblk`, `fdisk -l` do not show your flash drive then the reason is certainly not that it is not mounted. These commands do not care at all amout mounts. `lsblk` and `fdisk` just care about block devices, `lsusb` just cares about detected USB devices (even those unusable by the system due to software reasons).

If `lsusb` does not show a USB device which you just attached then either the device or the port is broken. It makes sense to run `dmesg -T | tail -n 25` after attaching a device in order to see whether the kernel recognised any USB activity at all. Maybe something was seen but errors prevented the device from being assigned a USB ID.

Answer (score -2):

Thanks for all the help guys, but I was able to get in contact with an expert in Chromebooks. He told me that it is not possible to create a bootable image through Linux on Chromebook, and gave me a workaround instead. Once again, thanks for the help!

Comment: Sorry, but your expert's advice sounds spurious. I see no reason why you should not be able to create a bootable USB in Linux on a Chromebook. Also, it is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Your question seems to be about mounting a USB drive, but here you are talking about creating a bootable drive? I recommend keeping your questions clear and focused - ask a second one about a different topic, if need be.

Comment: @Time4Tea the issue I was trying to solve was not being able to mount my usb drive to my Crostini terminal (I believe that's what it's called). To make a bootable drive through the terminal, I need to mount my drive, but I presume that feature is not available because it is in beta.